# List Validation Settings - Multi Line formatted Columns Missing from Create Formula

Tags: custom-list, validation, multiple-lines-of-text

I have a custom list in which some specific fields need to have additional validation which I am implementing through Validation Settings.

However, on the Validation Settings page, when I go to create my formula, the option to add in the columns that I have already formatted as Multiple Lines of Text do not appear in the list of columns to chose from.

Does anyone know why specifically a Multi Lines columns seem to be missing from the validation settings? If I change the format from Multi Lines to Single Line of Text, for example, it appears in the list, however, I do need the column to be a Multi Line format.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

[Multi-line text field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldmultilinetext.aspx) is not available in column picker of Validation Settings page since it is **not** supported in formula expressions.  But you could consider the following client-side approach.

### How to validate Multi-line text field in SharePoint

Probably one of the best ways to apply client-side validation in SharePoint 2010 and 2013 would be to override `PreSaveAction` handler.

> `PreSaveAction` function is a user defined function that allows to
>   override standard behavior for a Save button handler in List Forms on the client-side.

Let's say we need to validate `Notes` field in `Links` list to accept only letters, then the following steps demonstrate how to apply those changes:

Steps:

1. Open New Form page in Edit mode
2. Add Content Editor web part on the page
3. Insert the code provided below into `Content` property of Content Editor web
   part

Code:

```
<script>
function isLetter(val) { 
    var re = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
    return re.test(val);
} 


function PreSaveAction(){

    var commentsBox = findFieldControl('Notes');  //find field control by title
    if (!isLetter(commentsBox.val())) {
        var errorHtml = '<br/><span class="ms-formvalidation"><span role="alert">Only letters are allowed<br></span></span>';
        commentsBox.after(errorHtml);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function findFieldControl(fieldTitle)
{
    var control = $('[title="' + fieldTitle + '"]');
    return control;
}

</script>​​​​​​
```

**Result**

[image]

Some additional information about client-side validation in SharePoint 2010/2013 could be found in [this post](http://blog.vgrem.com/2014/03/14/introduction-to-client-forms-validation-in-sharepoint-2013/).

Comment: I checked your your solution, but it doesnt Change anything.
I changed the title 'Notes' to 'Input' like it is titeled in my list. Do I have to Change anything more? Thanks in advance,
Tobias

Comment: @Tobias, could you create a separate question by specifying what have you tried and what does not work?