# List Validation for Single line of text and multiple line of text

Tags: list, validation

I need to validate in item list, that all defined text fields are filled with text if a choice is set with `"valueB"`; With choice `"valueA"` the text field may not be filled.

I solved this with list Validation formlula:

```
=IF(Bereich="valueB";IF(OR(Text1="";Text2=""; Text3="");FALSE;TRUE);TRUE)
```

The formula works nice.

Now I have to add another text field `"text4"` which is a Multi line text field and cannot be used in this standard list validation.

So I tried with this Code from Vadim, but it doesnt work:
[How to validate Multi-line text field in SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/117913/list-validation-settings-multi-line-formatted-columns-missing-from-create-form/147307)

In Addition, how can I Color text fields, until they are filled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you add "text4" as a single line text column and adapt and save your formula.
After that you can change "text4" to a multi line column without touching your validation formula again.