# SharePoint Online Multiline text field form validation

Tags: sharepoint-online, multiple-lines-of-text, column-validation

I need a way to have form validation for multiline text fields when submitting a new record. I know characters like `%` are not legal characters but I need to be able to verify a multiline text field upon clicking the SAVE button.

I am not a developer so I am a bit limited. I tried to use javascript but I can't get it to work and I think if we turn on modern sites that option will not work either.

A little bit of guidance would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Only the following field types can be validated with the "Column Validation" feature:

•Single Line of Text

•Choice (single only)

•Number

•Currency

•Date & Time

If you want to validate value of a multiple-lines of text field, you need script to overwrite the `PreSaveAction` function on list form .

Yes, the modern list view does not support adding script, you need to switch back to the classic list view.

Here is a demo in the following thread about how to validate the multiple-lines of text field on the list form using script:

[List Validation Settings - Multi Line formatted Columns Missing from Create Formula](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/117913/list-validation-settings-multi-line-formatted-columns-missing-from-create-form/117931)