# Getting NULL from input field query when trying to validate it using Presaveaction after adding SharePoint Link to Multiple lines of text field

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list, sharepoint-on-prem, presaveaction, validation-error

I am trying to validate the Input and some other fields using Presaveaction function.

```
function presaveaction(){
if($('input[title*="FieldName"]').val().trim()){
alert('FieldName should not be left empty');
return false;
}
return true;
}
```

It is working fine all the scenarios **except the one below**.
[image]

**After adding a link to the Multiple lines of text field through an above option, input and other fields are not available in the js scripts and returning null**.

Any help on this?

Comment: Can you please add your current code to your question by editing it?

Comment: I have added it.

Comment: You cannot validate multiple lines of (rich) text column like this because it does not store the value in single "input" element. Check [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1373a5c0-eaf6-4cad-8fd4-1e69583a61d5/multi-line-enhanced-rich-text-i-am-not-able-to-validate-blank-or-not) and [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/117913/list-validation-settings-multi-line-formatted-columns-missing-from-create-form/117931)

Comment: I am not trying to validate multiple lines of text field using the above script. Until I am adding the SharePoint link to the multiple lines of text, I can validate any field using custom scripts. But after that scenario, all validations are getting failed and returning null. Please read my question.